# MSXML2.DOMDocument Object required error if file extension is not .xml

Tags: php, vbscript, xml-parsing, msxml, hta

Working on an application to retreive shipping rates as XML from a web service.  The web service is PHP based.  The client is VB Script, specifically HTA.

During initial development I used an XML file on the server as a test.  Here is the content of that file:

```
<shipping>
    <rate>
        <method>FEDEX GROUND</method>
        <description>FedEx Ground</description>
        <amount>10.00</amount>
    </rate>
    <rate>
        <method>FEDEX 2 DAY</method>
        <description>FedEx 2nd Day</description>
        <amount>20.00</amount>
    </rate>
    <rate>
        <method>FEDEX NEXT DAY</method>
        <description>FedEx Next Day</description>
        <amount>30.00</amount>
    </rate>
</shipping>
```

When I use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to get that file I have no issues using MSXML2.DOMDocument to parse the XML.

If I attempt to get the exact same XML from a PHP script, or even if I copy the XML file to a filename with a non-xml extension, like .txt, I get an Object Required error trying to access the document elements.

When getting the data from PHP I am setting the header like so:

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
```

Here is the VB Script code:

```
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.open "GET", "http://craig.clearos.lan/c9pets/api/shippingRates", False
xmlhttp.send
results=xmlhttp.ResponseText
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.load(xmlhttp.responseXML)
Set ratesNodeCollection = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.getElementsByTagName("rate")
```

This errors out on the last line with "Object required: 'xmlDoc.DocumentElement'"

If I change line 2 to this

```
'xmlhttp.open "GET", "http://craig.clearos.lan/sage/hello.xml", False
```

it works as expected.

Again, I have verified that the PHP code and the .txt file contain the exact same XML as the .xml file.

I have added parseError trapping and I'm getting the message "XML document must have a top level element."  This makes no sense to me.  There is a top level element named   I've also added  to the .xml file and the output of PHP.  This did not change anything.  I tried setting the header to text/xml instead of application/xml, which also did nothing.

For reference here is the very simple php code that builds the XML.

```
$shipping=array(0=>array('method'=>'FEDEX GROUND', 'description'=>'FedEx Ground', 'amount'=>'10.00'),
    1=>array('method'=>'FEDEX 2 DAY', 'description'=>'FedEx 2nd Day', 'amount'=>'20.00'),
    2=>array('method'=>'FEDEX NEXT DAY', 'description'=>'FedEx Next Day', 'amount'=>'30.00'));
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement('<shipping/>');
foreach($shipping as $row){
    $rate=$xml->addChild('rate');
    $rate->addChild('method', $row['method']);
    $rate->addChild('description', $row['description']);
    $rate->addChild('amount', $row['amount']);
}
Header('Content-type: application/xml');
print($retVal->asXML());
```

Comment: Check the value of the `ParseError` property: `WScript.Echo "0x" & Hex(xmlDoc.ParseError)`

Comment: Thank you.  I've added your suggested code and I'm getting "XML document must have a top level element."  I'm thinking that maybe this is an apache or php issue?  I've been testing the output of the php in a browser and it looks different than the .xml file, even though all the characters are the same.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but try setting the content type to `text/xml` instead of `application/xml`.

Comment: After much hair pulling, I finally figured out that even with the headers and the preamble, that what that php script was producing wasn't recognized as XML.  I think it might have something to so with the Slim() framework.  THanks for your help - the parse error trap is what got me there.

Comment: @CraigJacobs: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it so that others know that this isn't an open question any more. :)